# Command (using \ifthenelse) within 2nd optional (post) argument of footcite

Tags: biblatex, citing, conditionals, biber

I have defined a new command `\mypageref` to reference page numbers of text parts in my appendix. The begin of such a text part is labeled, e.g., by `\label{text_begin}`, and the end of the text part is labeled, e.g., by `\label{text_end}`. The statement is intended to either print, e.g., "S. 42" if the text part is entirely on page 42, or to print, e.g., "S. 42 - 44" if the text part is going over multiple pages. I use the `\ifthenelse` statement of the `ifthen` package. The command is defined as follows:

```
    \newcommand{\mypageref}[2]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pageref{#1}}{\pageref{#2}}}
      {S. \pageref{#1}}
      {S. \pageref{#1}\ --\ \pageref{#2}}
    }
```

It works fine in the main text and in footnotes. However, I have the situation, that my appendix contains text which also belongs to a "source" with an own entry in my bib file, lets say

```
    @misc{biblabel,
      author = {AAA},
      title = {BBB},
      year = 2014
    }
```

Now, I want to use

```
    \footcite[pre][\mypageref{text_begin}{text_end}]{biblabel}
```

which fails with the error: "Missing `\endcsname` inserted".

Interestingly,

```
    \footcite[\mypageref{text_begin}{text_end}][post]{biblabel}
```

works. In other words, using the `\mypageref` in the 1st optional argument (pre) works, but not in the 2nd optional argument (post). I use `biblatex` and `biber`. Note that `\footcite` as well as `\mypageref` work fine separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this source](http://tex.aspcode.net/view/635399273629833626294568/how-to-check-whether-two-labels-fall-on-the-same-page), I got a solution to my problem:

```
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{refcount}

    \newcommand{\mypageref}[2]{
      \ifnumequal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getpagerefnumber{#2}}
        {S. \pageref{#1}}
        {S. \pageref{#1}\ --\ \pageref{#2}}
    }
```